# Error:(251, 5) error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/pivotX' with config '

Tags: java, android

I want to build my project but I have two below errors:

```
app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml
and
.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/f77c6d1a88f01103cae33cf6888dffb6/res/values/values.xml

Error:(251, 5) error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/pivotX' with config ''.
Error:(251, 5) error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/pivotY' with config ''.
```

but I can't find error

Comment: Shared my answer here. The bug was fixed in beta8 https://stackoverflow.com/a/62821939/2810726