# Duplicate value for resource 'attr/pivotX' with config ' '

Tags: android, gradle

After a month, launched Android studio and on syncing with Gradle, this error pops up. Rebuilding/cleaning the project does not works and shows the same error again.

I have tried to rebuilding/clean and invalidate/restart the project but nothing seems to be working. I have searched out on this site about the problem but yet again nothing seems to be working. Would be really great if someone helps me with this one because I am stuck and can`t provide update my app.

`Android resource compilation failed
Output:  E:\Play Store Listings\Notepedia\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2616: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/pivotX' with config ''.`

`E:\Play Store Listings\Notepedia\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2616: error: resource previously defined here.
E:\Play Store 
Listings\Notepedia\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2616: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/pivotY' with config ''.
E:\Play Store Listings\Notepedia\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2616: error: resource previously defined here.`

`Command: C:\Users\Taseer.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\8dd90688e4f5a22b34a1a148f45c2455\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        E:\Play Store Listings\Notepedia\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        E:\Play Store Listings\Notepedia\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0`

**EDIT:** This is where the error leads to: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9nAz.jpg)

**EDIT 2:** Link to download(File removed)

Comment: pivot is already defined as view attribute. that might be the reason you are having this issue. try prefixing some label may be like transformPivotX and this might work. Do this for all the attribute you have in image shared.

Comment: Just tried it, on syncing the project again, it rebuilds and restores previous labels. Maybe is there any solution like migrating this project to new project? maybe?

Comment: @RahulKumar please add detailed description how to fix this issue

Comment: @IvanVovk I changed the label from "pivotX" and "pivotY" to "transformPivotX" and "transformPivotY". After that, rebuilt the project and everything started working fine. If you look into the picture I have shared you would see pivotX, just rename it to anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I am posting the comment as anwer

pivot is already defined as view attribute. that might be the reason you are having this issue. try prefixing some label may be like transformPivotX and this might work. Do this for all the attribute you have in image shared.

Comment: what image, what label. I dont have any names for it

Comment: @IvanVovk What exactly error are you facing? Does it says anything about "pivotX" or "pivotY"?

Comment: @TaseerAhmad the same issue as faced you. But I dont undestand what I have to fix. Open values.xml and fix attr there?

Comment: Yes, open values.xml. Click the link where error log takes you to. It will take you to and point to the line where the error is originating from. After that, look for an attribute named as "pivotX" and "pivotY". Rename pivotX to  "transformPivotX" and pivotY to "transformPivotY"

Comment: @Ivan search for declarable-style tag in your values folder. Then inside that you need to search for pivotX and replace it by something else. for example transformPivotX and same for pivotY.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I tried to implement new versiont of Constraint Layout(in gradle)

**implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'**

and I get this error. I dont want to edit any attribes, I do revert to stable version

**implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'**

And the error dessapears.

Comment: Good catch. But I think that updated version of constraint layout is better to use in project.

Comment: @TaseerAhmad may be you are right, but a bit later=) when it would be a release version, not an alpha. Any way, thanks

Answer (score 1):

That helped me.

1. Find library that cause that conflict (just remove libraries dependencies one by one and sync gradle).
2. Go to  External Libraries > "conflict library" > res > values
3. Open **values.xml** and find there an attribute with the **conflict name** (in that case it's 'pivotX') and **refactor that name** to any other.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and had to look through the beta changes. Found the problem has been fixed in beta8

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta8'
```